# Is "pass by value" synonymous with "functional programming"

Tags: programming-practices

Is "pass by value" synonymous with "functional programming" ?

1. Are there any iterative programming languages that are (largely) "pass by value"?
2. Are there any functional programming languages that are (largely) "pass by reference"?

Thanks.

Comment: Java is pass by value...

Comment: Functional programming is a software development model. It estimates and applies mathematical functions, rather than state or mutable data and imperative code threads. - More in wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

Comment: I am interested in a specific answers, (i) are there functional languages that, by default, are "pass by reference" and (ii) are there are iterative languages that, by default, are "pass by value". (the second question has been answered by assylias above)

Comment: It seems to me it would be kind of odd to have pass by reference as the default in a functional language, because p.b.r. makes it so easy to to cause side effects in distant places in your code.  Common Lisp has non-default ways to treat variables, which give effects like pass by reference in that you can change the value of a variable non-locally.  But that's not a case of being _largely_ pass by reference.  If you don't want to be able to modify what's passed in, but just want to delay evaluation of it, there are functional languages that do that.  I believe Haskell does, for example.

Comment: actual pass by reference is very rare now, most languages pass by value

Comment: The semantics of Haskell are such that it makes no difference whether you pass the immutable thing in by value or by reference.  In practice the compiler often passes by reference because that is more efficient.

Comment: Pass by value is a method of passing parameters through functions.  Functions can be used in both iterative and functional fashions, regardless of the method of passing parameters.  One doesn't have to do with the other.

Comment: @Mars: Actually, the difference between pbr and pbv cannot be observed in a functional language, and thus an implementor may choose either strategy depending on performance.

Comment: Good point @JörgWMittag.  I was using "functional language" as a loose stylistic description, including languages such as Scheme and Common Lisp.  Not sure what uday intended.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is "pass by value" synonymous with "functional programming" ?

No, They are not just "not synonymous", they are completely and utterly unrelated. They have absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with each other.

> Are there any iterative programming languages that are (largely) "pass by value"?

I am assuming you mean imperative programming languages. Yes, there are imperative programming languages which are pass by value. In fact, there are very few which aren't: C, Java, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, pretty much all Lisps, Smalltalk, Self, Newspeak, Io, Ioke, Seph, are just some of the examples. They are not just "largely" pass by value, they are pass by value. Period. No exceptions, no ifs, no buts.

C++, C#, Visual Basic.NET, PHP are pass by value by default, you need to *explicitly* ask for pass by reference, e.g. using the `ref` keyword in C#.

> Are there any functional programming languages that are (largely) "pass by reference"?

The difference between pass by value and pass by reference can only be observed when the reference is mutated. Functional programming languages don't allow mutation, ergo it is impossible to tell whether a functional programming language is pass by value or pass by reference. Language implementors make use of this by choosing either one of the two strategies depending on which one yields better performance for a particular piece of code.

For example, large objects will be passed by reference, but smaller objects where the object itself is as big as a reference or smaller (such as e.g. integers in a tagged pointer representation) will be passed by value.

Note also that both pass by value and pass by reference are eager evaluation strategies, whereas some of the more popular functional programming languages (e.g. Haskell, Frege) have non-strict semantics and thus are usually implemented using some form of lazy evaluation. Some of the more popular Haskell compilers for example use call by need with limited sharing.

Answer (score 4):

C is an imperative language that is pass by value. Fortran is an imperative language that is pass by reference. C# supports both functional programming (lambdas, etc.) and pass by reference.

Therefore, the answer is **no**, they are not synonymous.